# qt listwidget clear() unexpectedly trigger itemSelectionChanged()

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qlistwidget

in PyQt(Pyside6), I created a QListWidget:

- it shows 3 items of '1/2/3' when I click one 'show_123' Button
- it shows 3 items of 'a/b/c' when I click one 'show_abc' Button
- when I click '1' in the QListWidget, one Label shows '1'; click '2', shows '2'; click 'a' show 'a', etc

the 'show_abc' button simple code is as bellow, ('show_123' is similar)

```
listWidget1.clear()
listWidget1.addItems(['a','b','c'])
```

and pseudo code for updating Label is

```
listWidget1.itemSelectionChanged.connect(update_label)
```

**BUT, I found the "listWidget1.clear()" will trigger "listWidget1.itemSelectionChanged", so to call update_label. This is unexpected, I just want to 'clear&addItems' to refresh. how could I solve this problem**

Comment: Disconnect the signal from the function before clearing and then reconnect it again after adding items. Or use QSignalBlocker.

Comment: Surely the label text should be cleared when there's no selection? Otherwise, it will still show a number when the list only has letters, and *vice versa*. Thus, it seems you should change `update_label` so that it calls `self.label.clear()` if there's no current item or `self.listWidget1.selectedItems()` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I added "setCurrentItem(None)" before clear() to solve it, not found some more elegant way.

```
listWidget1.setCurrentItem(None)
listWidget1.clear()
listWidget1.addItems(...)
```

Comment: It won't work properly: if the user has selected some items, the signal would be emitted anyway.